# Setting Date X Days From Today

Tags: javascript

We are setting up a Google Trusted Store and need to populate the following span id field `ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE` with today's date plus 2 days:

```
<span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">ORDER_EST_SHIP_DATE</span>
```

With the output being in `YYYY-MM-DD` format

For example, today is *2015-02-25*. I need the line of code to post:

```
<span id="gts-o-est-ship-date">2015-02-27</span>
```

I also need to post another span id to be today's date plus 7 days:

```
<span id="gts-o-est-delivery-date">ORDER_EST_DELIVERY_DATE</span>
```

So two different dates based on today's date: 
- 1 that will be 2 days from today
- 1 that will be 7 days from today

```
function addDays(theDate, days) {
    return new Date(theDate.getTime() + days*24*60*60*1000);
}

var newDate = addDays(new Date(), 5);
```

Comment: Are you using Javascript to calculate the new date and update the span?  What code do you already have/tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript date has a build in method:

```js
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 2 /*days*/ );
var dateString = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
document.getElementById('gts-o-est-ship-date').innerHTML = dateString;
```

```html
<div id="gts-o-est-ship-date"></div>
```

Documentation on [toISOString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString)

Comment: Since when does JavaScript has a `Date.prototype.format`?

Comment: I have it from [here](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format). For now I will use toLocalFormat

Comment: `toLocalFormat` not standardized API, so fail on IE.

Answer (score 1):

First convert the date to a timestamp in microseconds using `Date.parse`:

Than add two and seven days to it in microseconds, convert back to human readable date.

```js
var timeStamp = Date.parse("2015-02-25");

//add two days, in microseconds = 60*60*24*2*1000
var TwoDays = 172800000;
var SevenDays = 604800000;

function convertToDate(timeStamp)
{
  var date = new Date(timeStamp);
  return date.toJSON().split("T")[0];
}

document.write(convertToDate(timeStamp+TwoDays)); //show two days in future
document.write("<br />");
document.write(convertToDate(timeStamp+SevenDays)); //show seven days in future
```

> This returns a UTC date. So you may need to convert this to the users locale. It's important that you pick a base times for all your time (UTC for example) and convert it to the users locale as a last step.