# populate 'today + x days' as form input value

Tags: javascript, html, forms, date

I'm new to html/javascript. Here's a snippet of the form I'm building:

```
<form name=qdbform>
<input type=date id=duedate>
</form>
```

duedate should always be x number of days after today. I'm attempting to use the below javascript:

```
<script>
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 3 /*days*/ );
var dateString = date.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
document.getElementById('duedate').innerHTML = dateString;
</script>
```

In other words, I would expect that when visiting the form now (7/16/2018) that 7/19/2018 populates in the form. Instead, nothing happens.

This script worked fine when I was used as described in this post: 
[Setting Date X Days From Today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729419/setting-date-x-days-from-today) but insn't working when I include in the form

Comment: Where/When is the script executed? ... hopefully after the form, right?

Comment: Second, an `input` use `.value`, not `.innerHTML`

Comment: Hi LGSon, that previous question ("using innerHTML with <input>") uses jargon that I'm not yet comfortable with so it didn't really help me because I'm a newby asking a question in 'business logic'. However, your note about changing .innerHTML to .value does answer my question. Is there a way in Stack Overflow to mark a comment as Solves My Question?

Comment: No, one accept answers that solve a question. In your case there is already an answer, so you could follow the duplicate link and upvote their answer(s).